# Find the longest sequence of ascending numbers in unsorted array

Tags: arrays

Suppose the `Array[10] = {10,6,11,9,-18,0,91,18,24,32}`
The largest sequence will be `10,11,18,24,32` or `-18,0,18,24,32`

The solution to this is make another `Array[10]` which will store the number of sequences. Starting from the last element 32 which makes just 1 sequence i.e. the number itself.

24 makes 2
18 makes 3
91 makes 1
0  makes 4
-18 makes 5
9 makes 4
11 makes 4
6 makes 4
10 makes 5

The output should be either 5 starting from -18 or 5 starting from 10.

Can anyone help me with the code please.

Answer (score 0):

more or less it will look like that, now you need to translate this to language what you are using

```
largestSequience = [];
temporaryArray = [];
for (element in array)
{
if (temporatySize not empty and temporarySize[lastElement]>=element)
   {
    if (temporaryArray.length > largestSequence.length) largestSequence = temporaryArray;
    temporaryArray = [element]

   }

temporaryArray.add(element)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want in C++. The running time is O(NlogN), in which N is the size of Array[]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
        int Array[10] = {10,6,11,9,-18,0,91,18,24,32};
        int p[10],next[10];
        int i,j,n=10;
        map<int,int> places;
        for(i=n;i>=0;i--){
                map<int,int>::iterator ii=places.upper_bound(Array[i]);
                if(ii==places.end()){ //no item on the right is larger
                        p[i]=1;
                        next[i]=-1; 
                }else{
                        next[i]=ii->second;
                        p[i]=p[ii->second]+1;
                }
                places[Array[i]]=i;
                ii=places.find(Array[i]);
                while(ii!=places.begin()){
                        ii--;
                        if(p[ii->second]<=p[i]){
                                places.erase(ii);
                        }else
                                break;
                        ii=places.find(Array[i]);
                }
        }
        int longestI=0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                if(p[i]>p[longestI])
                        longestI=i;
        }
        for(i=longestI;i>=0;i=next[i]){
                printf("%d\n",Array[i]);
        }
        return 0;

}
```